# Elasticsearch copy index data to a file curl query

Tags: elasticsearch

I am in the process of upgrading my elasticsearch cluster from 5.4 to 6.2.4.
I did a rolling upgrade from 5.4 to 5.6.
So, I see a kibana upgrade assistant that will help me out with the upgrade to 6.2.
But before upgrading to 6.2, I have to backup my data.
I can use the snapshot/restore api to do that. But I dont have any s3/azure/hdfs/ a shared mount drive to all the nodes in the cluster.

So, I have decided to just copy out the index data into a file and the index mappinga and setting info to a file.

The first thing I found was elasticsearch-dump (which I cant use).
I found the Get API and Multi Get API that can fetch me the data by giving an id value.
I couldn't get all the documents using the get api.

I get the data if I give an ID:
`curl -X GET -u elastic --cacert /etc/elasticsearch/ca.crt "https://elkpol28:9200/index_name/doc_type/AWxtwq8AV7vOb4sdXT8n?pretty"`

But How to get all the values and pipe them to a file something like this:

`curl -X GET -u elastic --cacert /etc/elasticsearch/ca.crt "https://elkpol28:9200/index_name/doc_type/*?pretty" > /opt/Elastic/test.log`

I got an error as expected for the above since `id *` doesn't exist.

What are the available options using python/Curl to get all the data of an index.

Elasticsearch version: 5.6

Comment: You can also snapshot your data into your [local filesystem](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/modules-snapshots.html#_shared_file_system_repository), which is much better than exporting it into JSON and reindexing it afterwards.

Comment: @Val The local filesystem you are referring, has to be a common share for all master and data nodes as per the doc which I do not have. Can you tell me a better solution than that.

Comment: Using curl, the problem will be that 1) if you have more than 10000 docs, you won't be able to store them in one go and 2) you'll store the documents in response format (i.e. embedded in the hits.hits array) which will make it difficult to reuse afterwards for reindexing. elasticdump would be my second choice (not sure why you can't use it). Another solution is to close your ES and then simply backup your data folders somewhere.